# Does not show half rating and how to select half rating on click function in Angular Star Rating?

Tags: angular, rating

I am using [Angular Star Rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/levon-angular-star-rating) plugin for showing rating in angular2. A problem is half rating is not displayed and does not select half rating on click event.

**Component.ts:-**

```
  onClickResult:IStarRatingOnClickEvent;

  getRatingValue = ($event:IStarRatingOnClickEvent) => {
    console.log('onClick $event: ', $event);
    this.onClickResult = $event;
  };
```

**Component.html:-**

```
  <star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" [rating]=2.6 [readOnly]="true" [showHalfStars]='true' (onClick)="getRatingValue($event)">
  </star-rating-comp>
```

Please tell us how to show half rating and on click select half rating. In any body used this plugin please tell us.

Comment: did u try `[rating]="2.6"` ?

Comment: Yes, but show same issue.

Comment: I cannot say what is causing the issue without debugging it but u can give [ngx_rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-rating) a shot

Comment: I have already used ngx_rating . In this plugin does not click event on rate icon.

Comment: I guess they have not implemented clicking half star yet, I just tried and its possible to show half star if you use svg

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora check my below answer with the demo

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from source code of the library :

```
<div class="star-container">
    <div class="star"
      (mouseenter)="onStarHover(star)"
      *ngFor="let star of stars"
      (click)="onStarClicked(star)">
        <i *ngIf="!svgVisible()" class="star-empty {{classEmpty}}"></i>
        <i *ngIf="!svgVisible()" class="star-empty {{classHalf}}"></i>
        <i *ngIf="!svgVisible()" class="star-filled {{classFilled}}"></i>
        <svg *ngIf="svgVisible()" class="star-empty default-star-empty-icon">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" [attr.xlink:href]="pathEmpty"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg *ngIf="svgVisible()" class="star-half default-star-half-icon">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" [attr.xlink:href]="pathHalf"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg *ngIf="svgVisible()" class="star-filled default-star-filled-icon">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" [attr.xlink:href]="pathFilled"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see , there is only one click event per each star. The stars array is fetched from the code :

```
static getStarsArray(numOfStars: number): Array<number> {
    let stars: Array<number> = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++) {
        stars.push(i + 1);
    }
    return stars;
}
```

So, it is very clear for me that the library does not have implementation for half star yet. The original CSS library has functionality to show half star thats why we can get half star if we use svg .

May be we can try to implement our own implementation using the CSS.

**Update**:

It looks like its not possible to implement clicking to get half star with that library.

But there are very good solutions with pure CSS like [this](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom component from this [repo](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted) as below,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-star',
    template: `
    <div class="crop" 
    [style.width.px]="starWidth"
    [title]="rating"
    (click)="onClick()">
    <div style="width: 86px">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </div>
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./star.comp.css']
})
export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() rating: number;
    starWidth: number;
    @Output() ratingClicked: EventEmitter<string> =
            new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.starWidth = this.rating * 86 / 5;
    }

    onClick(): void {
        this.ratingClicked.emit(`The rating ${this.rating} was clicked!`);
    }
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AHq07HBpGI8Gyvw2NJwO?p=preview)